# jquery ajax - why the code is not hitting done/completed block

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, json, ajax

we are making ajax call to a web server which serves pages by calling cgi script on the server side. I just want to debug the code flow and added DONE and COMPLETE ajax call backs . But DONE/COMPLETE code never get called.

The data is returned in JSON format . I could see error call back is executed in case the return JSON is invalid . Also I could see success get executed if all are proper. In which case DONE/COMPLETE get executed? . Why in my case , those call backs are not called at all?

```
$.ajax(
        {
            type: "POST",
            url: "http://10.227.5.3/cgi-bin/GetData.cgi",
            data: overload_sensitivity_frm_data,
            async:true,
            dataType: "JSON",

            success: function (successData) {
                console.log("successData >>"+successData);
            },
            error: function (errorData) {
                console.log("errorData >>"+errorData);
            },
            complete: function (completeData) {
                console.log("completeData >>"+completeData);
            },
            done: function (doneData) {
                console.log("doneData >>"+doneData);
            },

        });
```

Thanks.

Comment: did you see any error message in browser console?

Comment: No . There is no error message . I tried changing the order of the definition . Even i didn't see anything.

Comment: `done` is a function not  a property

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/s1mhpeqs/1/ - still the complete callback has to get executged

Comment: Is this problem with the server side implementation? . can you please let me know the status codes which calls complete and done.

Comment: Do you get to see the successData / errorData logs?

Comment: just comment dataType: "JSON", then try.. suppose its work..just try..and done function is not like that

Comment: @PraveenPuglia , yes i am getting success logs if all are proper and error log if json is invalid.

Comment: Can you post the data that you get when it's success?